# Setting image through SdWebImage gives “Error code=-1003” and using CFNetwork Diagnostics log "Err(-65554)"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsurlconnection, sdwebimage

Generating a tableCell's image part using `SDWebimage` block:

```
    [cell.i_imageView 
sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: item.imageUrl] 
    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no-image"] 
    options: SDWebImageRefreshCached 
    completed:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL * _Nullable imageURL) {

           if(!image)
               NSLog(@"image not loaded %@", error.description);
```

In most cases the image loads fine, but sometimes in SDwebimage's completion handler when it fails, it gives these error messages "Error code=-1003" and upon using CFNetwork Diagnostics log it gives "Err(-65554)".

After much research I have found out it's a DNS-related issue and have tested this theory out by using the following methods,

- Use VPN on an actual device
- Disconnect the WIFI and use Cellular data

To these aforementioned techniques the images reloads again, but I can't be betting on both these above mentioned methods while shipping the product, so any NSURLSession calls, SdWebImage methods that I might missing here that solves the problem, or maybe a way to turn cellular data on for these specific URLs

Comment: -1003 is NSURLErrorCannotFindHost error. Common error when there is no internet connection.

Comment: I'm sure the device has a stable connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue of using cooperate Wifi ISP which had these reservations with some URLs that were been test, only thing that was needed -- reconnect to new different Wifi or use cellular.

It was never related to SDWebimage